# Universal property of the quotient group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the canonical surjection $\pi: G\longrightarrow G/H$. For all group $L$ and all homomorphism $\varphi:G\longrightarrow L$ such that $\varphi(h)=1_L$ for all $h\in H$, there is a unique homomorphism $\tilde\varphi: G/H\longrightarrow L$ such that $\tilde \varphi\circ \pi=\varphi$.

Could someone tell me in what this is a very important property ? I don't see any interest on this property.

Comment: The following link might be of interest to you, although it speaks in the language of categories: http://jeremykun.com/2013/05/24/universal-properties/

Comment: A specific case of this is the first isomorphism theorem, which is ubiquitous in mathematics. It is a way of converting a homomorphism into an isomorphism - and knowing whether two groups are isomorphic is very useful.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, this universal property result answers a very natural question, namely the question of how the homomorphisms $G/H \to L$ look like. In fact, by the universal property, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the homomorphisms $G/H \to L$ and the homomorphisms $G \to L$ having $H$ in its kernel and this correspondence is given by composing with $\pi$.

Secondly, an object having a universal property is unique with this property up to isomorphy. In your case this means that if $\pi': G \to L'$ is a homomorphism with $H$ in its kernel and the property that for every $\varphi: G \to L$ which has $H$ in its kernel we have a factorization $\varphi = \varphi' \circ \pi'$ for a unique $\varphi': L' \to L$, then there exists an isomorphism $\psi :  G/H \cong L'$ such that $\pi' = \psi \circ \pi$.

As an example of how this can be used, let us consider quotients of quotients. If  $N$ is another normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, then $H/N$ is normal in $G/N$ and we want to consider $(G/N)/(H/N)$ which comes equipped with a canonical map $\pi_H: G/N \to (G/N)/(H/N)$. Let $\varphi: G \to L$ be a map with $H$ in its kernel, then it also contains $N$ in its kernel and we get a factorization $\varphi = \varphi' \circ \pi_N$ for a unique $\varphi' : G/N \to L$ where $\pi_N : G \to G/N$ is the canonical projection.
Now, the homomorphism $\varphi'$ has $H/N$ in its kernel (this follows from the above factorization), hence we get a unique $\varphi'' : (G/N)/(H/N) \to L$ with $\varphi'' \circ \pi_H = \varphi'$, thus $\varphi''$ is unique with $\varphi'' \circ (\pi_H \circ \pi_N) = \varphi$, so $(G/N)/(H/N)$ has the same universal property as $G/H$ (with respect to the morphism $\pi_H \circ \pi_N$), hence $G/H \cong (G/N)/(H/N)$.
If you would show this without using the universal property you would have to define the isomorphism directly and show that it is well-defined (independent of the coset representative), a homomorphism etc. This is not that difficult. But in my opinion, the proof using the universal property also tells you *why* these groups are isomorphic the reason being that they satisfy the same universal property.